# cross compilation for ARM: error no such file or directory

Tags: gcc, c, arm, cross-compilation

I have written simple Hello world program and compiled it with `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` compiler. It compiles well but when i try to execute it on ARM machine it complains "no such file or directory". 
I think `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` is for embedded Linux only due to `e(mbedded)abi`. Is it different from ARM Linux ABI?

Please help me to solve this problem

code is here

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello world !\n");
  return 0;
}
```

compiled as

```
> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -o crosscomp hello.c
```

When i execute this crosscomp on target ARM machine error is 
crosscomp no such file or dir

**EDIT**
When I was using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` the entry point was not matching with the target machine entry point (readelf -l crosscom) but when I compiled with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` entry point matched with target machine. But now error becomes permission denied on ./crosscomp. I tried with sudo which says crosscomp: no such command.

Comment: It just says "no such file or directory" with no file being mentioned?

Comment: file is present in the dir :)

Comment: What file??  You said you wrote "simple Hello world program", that does not access any files, you won't get much help now if you do not (a) show us your actual code and (b) show us the full text of the error message!

Comment: So just to be 100%, you're typing `crosscomp` and you have checked that `.` is on your PATH?

Comment: yep  my dear I am doing like this :)

Comment: Well if it were me I'd look at `ldd crosscomp` and `strace crosscomp`, and maybe see how it behaves with the `printf` commented out.

Comment: For those who have similar issue, here is the question on SO -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929092/trying-to-run-a-cross-compiled-executable-on-target-device-fails-with-no-such-f

Answer (score 1):

**How to identify the problem?**

```
file cross_compiled_executable
```

Contains something like:

```
interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

and the problem is that that file does not exist on the target.

**How to solve the problem?**

Use a proper compiler, either:

- the person who created the disk image must provide you the cross compiler or tell you exactly how to build it, e.g. with [crosstool-ng](https://crosstool-ng.github.io/).
- compile your own image and cross compiler, e.g. with [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/). Here is [an example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat).
- use a native compiler on the target. But generally targets are much slower than your host, and space constrained, so you likely don't want to do this.

  You might also be able to use a functional emulator such as QEMU to build, and then only run the programs on a slower platform, e.g. gem5 or a slow board.

Just hacking up the `interpreter` is potentially not enough, notably you have to ensure binary compatibility between the program and the target libc, or program and kernel interfaces (syscalls, `/proc`, etc.) if you try to use `-static` (the target kernel might be too old and not contain the required interfaces). The only robust solution is to use the correct toolchain.